# Excel : have cell range stored in cell to be used by combobox

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using a ComboBox (basically a drop-down list) in excel, and I would like to select a value from a range. Thing is, I have around 15 of those comboboxes that are linked to the same list, and I'd like to not have to modify the ranges for all of them if I add a value to my list.

Hence my idea of telling the dropdown to take the array given in cell A1 of my data sheet as input for the actual array...

I'm not sure I'm being clear so here's an example : my list is in the range A3:A25. I want to have "A3:A25" written in cell A1, and have my dropdown list take the value of A1 as the actual range, so that if I add an entry to the list I can change A1 to "A3:A26" and not have to change all of my lists.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a column in an Excel Table as the Data Validation list source. Then new values are reflected automatically because the structured reference always refers to them. Avoid raw references wherever possible.

Comment: @underscore_d Thanks for that fast answer, can you elaborate on what you mean ?

Comment: First show what you've done so far, i.e. how this ComboBox is implemented, so no one wastes their time guessing. But I meant exactly what I said: once the values are stored in a column of an Excel Table, any Data Validation list that refers to them - whether by the column name (via a named range) or by a raw reference - will update whenever the used range of the table expands due to new value(s) being added.

Comment: well the input range is basically written as a raw "A3:A25"

Answer (score 2):

Change the reference to:

```
=$A:$A
```

Be sure to tick `Ignore blank`.

Comment: Hmm, that's simpler than what I thought. I'd still recommend using Tables wherever possible though. :P

Comment: @underscore_d `Named range` would be as far as I'd go

Comment: I understand your idea of including the entire column but there are stuff in A1 and A2 I don't want included in the list, and there is no option to "ignore blank" in the dropdown's format control options

Comment: You are doing it using `Data Validation` from `Data` tab using the `List` option?

Comment: I'm using Developper -> insert -> ComboBox (form control).
I don't see List in the Data tab...

Comment: @Saryk Consider using the `Data Validation` variant if `Combo Box` isn't mandatory.

Comment: I don't know how data validation creates drop lists :/

Comment: @Saryk If you set your Data Validation to "Allow: List" and ticket "In-cell dropdown", then the cell will act like a combobox for you.  Just set the Source to `=List` to look at your Named Range for the options

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just selected my list and called it "List" (right click, -> define name), and defined the input range as "List".
Now if I add a value, I just have to redefine List.

Thanks

Comment: This is a subpar solution because it requires you to - remember to - update the list whenever value(s) are added. What we have suggested does not.

Comment: You can go to Formulas > Name Manager, and change the "Refers to:" to a dynamic formula that will automatically resize to fit, like `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,2,0,MAX(1,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-2),1)`